# How to add track number metadata for an MP4 file using Mutagen?

Tags: python, mutagen

Every other tag seems to work e.g. title, cover art, artist but I encounter an error for the track number tag [trkn] every time

```
import mutagen
from mutagen import MP4, MP4Cover

filePath = 'LoadFiles/UserUpload/test.mp4'
mp4_meta = MP4(filePath)

print("Enter the following")
title = input("Title: ")
mp4_meta['\xa9nam'] = title #works

trackno = input("Track No.: ")
mp4_meta['trkn'] = trackno #nope

mp4_meta.save()
```

In the mutagen documentation it states:

```
Tuples of ints (multiple values per key are supported):

‘trkn’ – track number, total tracks
```

What's the fix to this?

Comment: Where's the error?

Comment: ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 2, got 1)

Comment: you haven’t shown what input you’re handing to `trackno` via `input` but it’s telling you it wants a tuple of two `int`s and you’re only giving it one

Answer (score 3):

You need to provide a tuple for this field, including the total number of tracks.

Try the following:

```py
trackno = input("Track No: ")
totaltracks = input("Total No of Tracks: ")
mp4_meta['trkn'] = [(trackno, totaltracks)]
```

Comment: As @user19702899 mentioned in their response, you must wrap the tuple in a list to avoid a ```ValueError```. This is not well defined in the [docs](https://mutagen.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/mp4.html#mutagen.mp4.MP4Tags). I think this should be the accepted answer, but @lys I would recommend editing it to match the other user's change for the last line: ```mp4_meta['trkn'] = [(trackno, totaltracks)]```. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You actually need to provide an iterable of tuples.
Same as lys' answer except for the last line (where a list containing a single tuple of 2 ints is set as the `trkn` value):

```
trackno = input("Track No: ")
totaltracks = input("Total No of Tracks: ")
mp4_meta['trkn'] = [(trackno, totaltracks)]
```